# find and replace hex digits with blanks

Tags: r, regex, string, hex

How do I replace Unicode hex digits with blanks?  While scraping a website, I've found character strings that print as blanks, but are not blanks.  For example:

```
print(str)
```

prints

```
3 Max. 11
```

but

```
print(charToRaw(str))
```

prints

```
33 c2 a0 4d 61 78 2e 20 31 31
```

How can I replace the hex digits 0xc2a0 with a single blank (" ")?

I have tried

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(str, "[^[:alnum:]]", " ")
```

But that also replaces the period

Comment: Please provide [reproducible sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: c2 a0 is the UTF-8 encoding of U+00A0, NO-BREAK SPACE. You'll be better off using a unicode-aware string function to replace that character with a normal space than dealing with raw UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: A quick search for 'R string functions' suggests that something like `gsub("\u00a0", " ", str)` might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Shawn's suggestion works perfectly - thank you Shawn. Refer to his comments above.

The answer is

```
gsub("\u00a0", " ", str)
```